# Skipping over error message in R

Tags: r, loops, try-catch

I've read a lot about using `tryCatch()` (from this site and others) but I can't seem to get it to work. I know this is a redundant question, and I apologize, but I could really use the help.

`read.rwl()` breaks my loop, as some of the data I am trying to read are messy. I want to skip any URLs from `list.rwl` that break my loop, while at the same time saving as an object the URLs that would otherwise break the loop.

```
itrdb <- read.csv ("itrdb.csv")
itrdb.rwl <- (itrdb [,7])

library (dplR)

for (i in 1:length(itrdb)) {
list.rwl <- as.character (rwl.crn [1] [i])
skip_with_message = simpleError('Did not work out')
x <- tryCatch(read.rwl (list.rwl), error = function(e) skip_with_message)
}
```

Comment: If you are using functions from non-base packages you should include library() calls for everything that is needed. AND you should include dput for objects that are being used.

Comment: Try re-reading some of those sources. I doubt they are suggesting you use `tryCatch` as you are above.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I know I am not using tryCatch remotely right. I have tried other variations to no avail, hence why I posted my question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you catch the error using `tryCatch`, you can do something with it. In the below example, I just capture the error (or produce a random number), but you can condition to produce NA or whatever might be appropriate for your flow. See `?tryCatch` for more examples.

```
x <- as.list(rep(NA, 10))

set.seed(357)
for (i in 1:10) {
  feelin.lucky <- runif(1)

  if (feelin.lucky >= 0.5) {
    x[[i]] <- tryCatch({
      simpleError("this is error")
    }, error = function(e) e)
  } else{
    x[[i]] <- rnorm(1)
  }
}

> x
[[1]]
[1] -1.597783

[[2]]
[1] 0.3947471

[[3]]
<simpleError: this is error>

[[4]]
<simpleError: this is error>

[[5]]
<simpleError: this is error>

[[6]]
<simpleError: this is error>

[[7]]
<simpleError: this is error>

[[8]]
<simpleError: this is error>

[[9]]
[1] -0.7539072

[[10]]
[1] -0.4690151
```